# Deconstruct with same number of parameters but different signature -> compiler eror

Tags: c#-7.0

*I believe that this question is different from the linked duplicate because the linked question and answer don't directly address the same issue (I have added an update below that hopefully illustrates this).*

Why is an error returned when there are two Deconstruct methods on a class with the same number of arguments but different types - see code below. Multiple `Deconstruct` methods with different numbers of arguments are fine. Compiler only complains when the 'Deconstruct' methods have the same number of arguments even though the arguments are different types

I would have thought `Deconstruct` would work the same way as other methods where methods can be overloaded by signature (same number of arguments, different types). Not sure it actually makes sense for a class to have two Deconstruct methods with different signatures or different number of arguments (see comments), but I was wondering if this error is due to a technical limitation or a design feature to prevent people doing this.

```
var person = new Person { ID = 123, FirstName = "Bob", MiddleName = "Tim", LastName = "Smith" };
//error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Person.Deconstruct(out string, out string, out string)' and 'Person.Deconstruct(out int, out string, out string)'
// Deconstruct instance or extension method was found for type 'Person', with 3 out parameters and a void return type.
(string a, string b, string c) = person; //<=Errors on person here

...

public class Person
{
    public bool ID { get; set; }
    public int FirstName { get; set; }
    public int MiddleName { get; set; }
    public int LastName { get; set; }

    public void Deconstruct(out int fname, out int mname, out int lname)
    {
        fname = FirstName;
        mname = MiddleName;
        lname = LastName;
    }
    public void Deconstruct(out bool id, out int fname, out int lname)
    {
        id = ID;
        fname = FirstName;            
        lname = LastName;            
    }
}
```

**Update**

The answer can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1092)
Specifically:

> if there are overloads how this works then? `var (x, y) = foo;`

That is, there is no way to tell which overload to call when using var. That got me thinking about what would happen when overloading out methods and assigning to var. E.g. adding the following methods to `Person`

```
    public void Foo(out int i)
    {
        i = 1;            
    }
    public void Foo(out bool i)
    {
        i = false;            
    }
```

Then gives the following behaviour:

```
        person.Foo(out int k); //calls Foo(out int i)
        person.Foo(out bool m); //calls Foo(out bool i)


        //Error CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Person.Foo(out int)' and 'Person.Foo(out bool)
        person.Foo(out var i );
```

Which seems inconsistent with Deconstruct. Why does method overloading work so long as there is no var, but Deconstruct doesn't allow it even when assigning to different types?

Comment: The example code fails because both overloads have the same amount of parameters (which is not allowed) - If they have a different number of parameters it should work. The closest to an "official" explanation I can find is from the notes of a language design meeting ([link](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/0709623617764880198f972d66845e88a89fe149/meetings/2016/LDM-2016-09-06.md)): *"We should look only at the arity of the `Deconstruct` method. If there's more than one with the given arity, we fail."*

Comment: That is the point of my question - why does it fail?

Comment: Like tuples, deconstructions use a positional approach: break this into n elements. For types that aren't tuples, the `Deconstruct` does the job, and it only needs to know the cardinality (how many elements this can break into).  
It does not seem useful to be able to get different sets of elements. Instead, you should have a single `Deconstruct` that returns the "natural" elements, then discard those you don't need in some scenarios.

Comment: @JulienCouvreur - I agree that having different sets of elements does not seem strictly correct for deconstructing an object into its constituents, but the compiles does allow it. You can have Deconstruct methods that have different parameter numbers, just not different signatures - why is that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# deconstruction and overloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47195668/c-sharp-deconstruction-and-overloads)

Comment: @DavidArno I would argue, that this is a more direct question. The other is not obviously the same, however the answer lies in the link that you gave in the other answer, i.e. how would it work for var only? So thanks, that answers the question. If you answer as such I will accept it. Otherwise if everyone decided it is a dupe, that is fine too - I have my answer :)

Comment: @acarlon I don't expect multiple Deconstruct methods of different cardinality to be common scenario (I don't think it makes very much sense). It is supported as a side-effect of looking up by cardinality, which is required since cardinality for deconstruction isn't fixed. Maybe someone will come up with a convincing use case, but I haven't seen one yet.

Comment: @JulienCouvreur - agree that the different cardinality use-case is fringe at best. The problem remains that the behaviour is not intuitive compared to other methods taking out parameters (as per my update to Q). I was taking some people through the way that Deconstruct works and this was highlighted as not working they way they expected. A single deconstruct with discards would have seemed a better approach both in terms of what a Deconstruct does and conforming with the way that other methods behave.